# Maclaurin Series (How to proceed)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let$$f(x)=x^3e^{x^2}$$

Find $f^{(7)}(0)$ by Maclaurin Series.

My attempt,

$$x^3e^{x^2}=x^3 \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2)^n}{n!}$$

$$=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+3}}{n!}$$

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, we know that
$$ f(x)=x^3 e^{x^2} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{x^{2m+3}}{m!} \tag{A} $$
on the other hand, we know that
$$ f(x)=x^3 e^{x^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)\,x^n}{n!}\tag{B} $$
hence by the unicity of the Taylor series we have that $f^{(7)}(0)$ is given by $7!$ times the coefficient of $x^7$ in the RHS of $(A)$, i.e. $f^{(7)}(0)=\frac{7!}{2!} = \color{red}{2520}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: What is the term with $x^7$? And what happens when you compute the $7$th derivative?

Comment: Further Hint: $2n+3=7$ implies $n = 2$, so all terms other than $\frac{x^7}{2!}$ will become 0 when when you take the seventh derivative at 0 and this term will be a constant.